# Pass IEnumerable<T> as an argument of method and repository pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, collections, repository

I've seen tutorials of `Unit Testing` and I've never seen that `IEnumerable<T>` used as an argument of method. All authors use `Repository pattern` and `Service layers` to interact with data, that is, authors of tutorials get data in `Service layer` by `Repository` and there is no need to pass collections between the methods of `Service layer`.

However, I've written a simple quiz game which imitates `Repository pattern` and **when I started writing unit test methods, then I realized that many of my methods has arguments type of `IEnumerable<T>`**.

This is a simple quiz game where user can give simple answers to simple questions . For example, quiz asks question, then program will remember the answer of player and in the end program will calculate the overall score of the player answers. e.g. "How many continents are there on the Earth?", then quiz shows 4 possible answers, and then quiz remembers answers.

The whole code of my quiz game looks like this:

**Model classes:**

```
public class Answer
{
    public Answer(int idAnswer, int idQuestion, string content)
    {
        IdAnswer = idAnswer;            
        IdQuestion = idQuestion;
        Content = content;
    }

    public int IdAnswer { get; }
    public string Content { get; }
    public int IdQuestion { get; }
}

public class Question
{
    public Question(int idQuestion, string content)
    {
        IdQuestion = idQuestion;
        Content = content;
    }

    public int IdQuestion { get; }
    public string Content { get; }
}

public class QuestionAnswer
{
    public QuestionAnswer(int idQuestion, int idAnswer)
    {
        IdQuestion = idQuestion;
        IdAnswer = idAnswer;
    }
    public int IdQuestion { get; set; }
    public int IdAnswer { get; set; }
}
```

**Program class:**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   IQuestionRepository questionService = Factory.CreateInstance<QuestionRepository>();
   var questions = questionService.GetQuestions();

   IAnswerRepository answerService = Factory.CreateInstance<AnswerRepository>();
   var possibleAnswers = answerService.GetPossibleAnswers(questions);
   var playerAnswers = GetPlayerAnswers(questions, possibleAnswers);
   IQuestionAnswerRepository questionAnswerRepository = 
       Factory.CreateInstance<QuestionAnswerRepository>();
   var correctAnswers = questionAnswerRepository.GetCorrectAnswers(questions);

   ICountPlayerScoreBySum playerScores = 
       Factory.CreateInstance<CountPlayerScoreBySumService>();
   var playerScore = playerScores.CountPlayerScoreBySum(playerAnswers, correctAnswers);

   var winScoreString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WinScore");
   int winScore = 0;
   int.TryParse(winScoreString, out winScore);

   Console.WriteLine( playerScore == winScore ? 
        $"Wow! You are a winner! Your score is {playerScore}" 
        : $"Try again! It is just the lesson to win! Your score is {playerScore}");
}
```

The method `GetPlayerAnswers` of `Program` class:

```
private static IEnumerable<Answer> GetPlayerAnswers(IEnumerable<Question> questions, 
    IEnumerable<Answer> possibleAnswers)
    {
        List<string> allowedAnswers = new List<string>()
            {
                Constants.Constants.Answers.A,
                Constants.Constants.Answers.B,
                Constants.Constants.Answers.C,
                Constants.Constants.Answers.D,
            };

        var playerAnswers = new List<Answer>();

        foreach (var question in questions)
        {
            var possibleAnswersViewModel = possibleAnswers
                .Where(a => a.IdQuestion == question.IdQuestion)
                .OrderBy(a=>a.IdAnswer)
                .Select((a, i) => new PlayerAnswerViewModel { 
                    Content = $"{ IntToLetters(i)}. {a.Content}", 
                    IdAnswer = a.IdAnswer, 
                    IdQuestion = a.IdQuestion, 
                    PlayerKey = IntToLetters(i) 
            });                

            AskQuestion(question, possibleAnswersViewModel);

            while (true)
            {
                var playerKey = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString().ToUpper();
                Console.WriteLine();
                if (!allowedAnswers.Contains(playerKey))
                {
                    AskQuestion(question, possibleAnswersViewModel, true);
                }
                else
                {
                    var answer = possibleAnswersViewModel
                        .Where(a => a.PlayerKey == playerKey)
                        .FirstOrDefault();
                    if(answer != null)
                        playerAnswers.Add(new Answer(
                            answer.IdAnswer, 
                            question.IdQuestion, 
                            playerKey));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return playerAnswers;
    }
```

The methods `AskQuestion` and `IntToLetters` of `Program` class:

```
private static void AskQuestion(Question question, 
     IEnumerable<PlayerAnswerViewModel> possibleAnswers, 
     bool showPossibleKeys = false)
{
        if (showPossibleKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Possible keys are A, B, C or D");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(question.Content);
        possibleAnswers
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a.Content));
}

public static string IntToLetters(int value)
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    result = (char)('A' + value % 26) + result;
    return result;
}
```

Repositories:

```
public interface IAnswerRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Answer> GetPossibleAnswers(IEnumerable<Question> questions);
}

interface IQuestionAnswerRepository
{
    IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> GetCorrectAnswers(IEnumerable<Question> questions);
}

interface IQuestionRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions();
}
```

And implementation of repositories. AnswerRepository:

```
class AnswerRepository : IAnswerRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Answer> GetPossibleAnswers(IEnumerable<Question> questions)
    {
        return new List<Answer>() {
            new Answer(11, 3, "Sequoia"), new Answer(12, 3, "Berch"), new Answer(13, 3, "Lindens"), new Answer(14, 3, "Alder"),
            new Answer(1, 1, "1"), new Answer(2, 1, "2"), new Answer(3, 1, "5"), new Answer(4, 1, "6"),
            new Answer(7, 2, "More than 1"), new Answer(8, 2, "More than 2"), new Answer(9, 2, "More than 5"), new Answer(10, 2, "More than 6"),
            new Answer(15, 4, "yes, I do!"), new Answer(16, 4, "Sure!"), new Answer(17, 4, "Exactly"), new Answer(18, 4, "Yeap!"),
            new Answer(19, 5, "yes, I do!"), new Answer(20, 5, "Sure!"), new Answer(21, 5, "Exactly"), new Answer(22, 5, "Yeap!"),
            new Answer(23, 6, "yes, I do!"), new Answer(24, 6, "Sure!"), new Answer(25, 6, "Exactly"), new Answer(26, 6, "Yeap!"),
            new Answer(27, 7, "yes, I do!"), new Answer(28, 7, "Sure!"), new Answer(29, 7, "Exactly"), new Answer(30, 7, "Yeap!")
        }.Where(qa => questions
            .Select(q => q.IdQuestion)
            .Contains(qa.IdQuestion)
        );
    }
}
```

**QuestionAnswerRepository. Imitation of getting correct answers of questions from Database:**

```
public class QuestionAnswerRepository : IQuestionAnswerRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> GetCorrectAnswers(IEnumerable<Question> questions)
    {
        return new List<QuestionAnswer>() {
            new QuestionAnswer(1, 1),
            new QuestionAnswer(2, 2),
            new QuestionAnswer(3, 3),
            new QuestionAnswer(4, 4),
            new QuestionAnswer(5, 1),
            new QuestionAnswer(6, 1),
            new QuestionAnswer(7, 1),
            new QuestionAnswer(8, 1),
            new QuestionAnswer(9, 1),
            new QuestionAnswer(10, 1)
        }            
        .Where(qa => questions
            .Select(q=>q.IdQuestion)
            .Contains(qa.IdQuestion)
        );
    }
}
```

QuestionRepository:

```
public class QuestionRepository : IQuestionRepository
{
    public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions()
    {
        return new List<Question>() {
            new Question(1, "How many are there contintents?"),
            new Question(2, "How many are there colours?"),
            new Question(3, "What is the tallest tree?"),
            new Question(4, "Do you like dolphins?"),
        };
    }
}
```

and CountPlayerScoreBySumService:

```
public class CountPlayerScoreBySumService : ICountPlayerScoreBySum
{
    public int CountPlayerScoreBySum(IEnumerable<Answer> playerAnswers, 
        IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> correctAnswers)
    {
        var sum = 0;
        foreach (var userAnswer in playerAnswers)
        {
            var correctAnswer = correctAnswers
                .Where(a => a.IdQuestion == userAnswer.IdQuestion)
                .FirstOrDefault();

            if (correctAnswer != null) {
                if (userAnswer.IdAnswer == correctAnswer.IdAnswer)
                    sum += 1;
            }
        }

        return sum;
    }
}
```

and Factory service:

```
public class Factory
{
    public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

However, my signatures of methods looks like this. Many methods have arguments type of array:

```
private IEnumerable<Answer> GetPlayerAnswers(IEnumerable<Question> questions, 
    IEnumerable<Answer> possibleAnswers)
{
    ...
}
```

Is it okay? Is it a code smell to pass collections as arguments of a method? Or my quiz game is not properly designed? If yes, please be very kind, to advice me how design of an application can be improved.

In addition, I've pushed all my code of [Quiz game code into GitHub](https://github.com/NiceStepUp/Quiz).

Comment: Could you [edit] your question please and explain what the quiz is about? We need this for context. Otherwise if you're not interested in a general review you should try [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @t3chb0t Thank you for your attention, I've edited my question and explained what the quiz about.

Comment: @Mathematics thanks for your comment. Upvoted. Could you show me please where `Repository` called as `Service`

Comment: @Mathematics thank you very much for ERD. It is better than my tables as I have conjunction table to match a right answer to a question. This design of tables will give me less repositories. You should write your comments as an answer and I will upvote you. These are really helpful comments!

Comment: @StepUp I added answer to your question as suggested, feel free to ask any question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no general rule for using `IEnumerable` or not but there is one that says that you should use the most abstract representation of something because it gives you the most felxibility in what you can pass to such method because there would be fewer restrictions.

This means if you are iterating a collection and you do this only once then `IEnumerable<T>` is perfect because there is virtually nothing more general than this. However, if you plan to use `Add` or `Count` or iterate a collection multiple times then something meterialized would be more appropriate like `IList<T>` or `ICollection<T>`.

> ```
> public int CountPlayerScoreBySum(IEnumerable<Answer> playerAnswers, 
>     IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> correctAnswers)
> {
>     var sum = 0;
>     foreach (var userAnswer in playerAnswers)
>     {
>         var correctAnswer = correctAnswers
>             .Where(a => a.IdQuestion == userAnswer.IdQuestion)
>             .FirstOrDefault();
>
>         if (correctAnswer != null) {
>             if (userAnswer.IdAnswer == correctAnswer.IdAnswer)
>                 sum += 1;
>         }
>     }
>
>     return sum;
> }
> ```

Here, e.g. the first argument is ok, it's iterated only once but `correctAnswers` is used multiple times inside the loop so it probably should be something like `IList<T>` to make it more predictible and to inform the caller that you are going to use it more then once because it might otherwise execute some lengthly query.

You could also materialize it inside the method but this is not always a good idea and to make such decisions requires to take a look at the big picture and the entire design. Sometimes it's acceptable, another time it might not be the case.

So the bottom line is, don't *stupidly* use any type because some book says so but rather look carefully which type is the simplest one you can use and gives you the required felxibility at the same time. You have to decide in on case by case basis. You'll mostly end up with `IEnumerable<T>` anyway but make it a sensible decision and not *I've heard that...*.

Comment: Thanks for so great answer! Is it appropriate to ask you here or should I create another question to  make a code review of my whole program? Is it possible to get comments of my quiz game?

Comment: @StepUp your question is only 45min old --- give it some time, I'm sure more answers will appear later ;-)

Comment: ok. Is it appropriate to ask you here or should I create another question to make a code review of my whole program? Is it possible to get comments of my quiz game?

Comment: Why would you say that you should use the most abstract type for an *output* value? An `ICollection<T>` or an `IList<T>` **is** an `IEnumerable<T>`. So you lose no flexibility by returning a supertype, you **gain** flexibility, because you provide addtional functionality (which you might choose to ignore). An *input* value is a different story though. You want to put a minimum burden on the caller, so it is generally a good idea to ask for the minimum type that works for you.

Comment: @Sefe AKA Postel's Law.

Comment: @Safe I'm not talking about _out_ parameters. In this case you're right, it would not hurt to return a derived one.

Comment: @t3chb0t why do you think passing an enumerable makes the caller assume it is only enumerated once? If you want something that can only be enumerated once you pass an enumerator. I think it is totally fine to enumerate an enumerable multiple times. That is why enumerators are not enumerable even though they could just return this.

Comment: Is it enough to change `IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> correctAnswers` to `List<QuestionAnswer> correctAnswers`? Could you please, tell me, how it helps to reduce length of query length?

Comment: @StepUp I didn't say anything about reducing the length of the query... it isn't supposed to. I don't understand your question.

Comment: @t3chb0t ` it might otherwise execute some lengthly query.` Is it enough to change IEnumerable<QuestionAnswer> correctAnswers to List<QuestionAnswer> correctAnswers? But I cannot understand the profit of this. Could you please very kind to explain this statement in code?

Comment: @StepUp oh, now I see what you mean ;-) the _lengthy query_ stands for a linq expression that might take some time to execute. I'm not sure if you know that `IEnumerable<T>` means _deferred_ execution and there is now guarantee that behind it is a list or an array and if you let it do the whole linq stuff each time, you might create a bottleneck in you application. In your case there is a chance that the entire `GetCorrectAnswers` method would be executed `foreach` item in the loop.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing inherently wrong with using `IEnumerable<T>`, just as there would be nothing wrong with using `List<T>`. Whatever collection type you choose to accept or return is far more a matter of your application's needs than any style guide.

For example, if you were writing a public-facing API, you would likely want to be most permissible in what you accept in order to make it easy for clients to use that API. In that case, using `IEnumerable<T>` would allow any collection type (including arrays) to be passed to your methods.

On the other hand, if you were writing high-performance code that is internal to your application, you'd probably use `List<T>` and pass it between your (presumably private) methods (using concrete types is slightly faster than interfaces).

Remember that style guides are just that - **guides**. It's up to you the programmer to apply those guidelines intelligently and logically.

Answer (score 1):

Changing comments to answer on OP request. I am not answering the direct question asked by OP but few comments about the overall architecture and design of there solution which may indirectly solve the issue OP is worried about, passing collections as parameters.

```
IQuestionRepository questionService = Factory.CreateInstance<QuestionRepository>();
```

Light heartly, never ever create an object from repository and name it a service, it makes code confusing for people me like who following onion architecture as show below,

[image]

Also in C# usually objects are initialled together WHEN you are only initiating them for calling a single function or maybe 2 and there is no risk of memory leak, it also makes code more readable. Did you thought about using DI ?

```
   IQuestionRepository questionService = Factory.CreateInstance<QuestionRepository>();
   IAnswerRepository answerService = Factory.CreateInstance<AnswerRepository>();
   IQuestionAnswerRepository questionAnswerRepository = Factory.CreateInstance<QuestionAnswerRepository>();
   ICountPlayerScoreBySum playerScores = Factory.CreateInstance<CountPlayerScoreBySumService>();

   var possibleAnswers = answerService.GetPossibleAnswers(questions);
   var questions = questionService.GetQuestions();
   var playerAnswers = GetPlayerAnswers(questions, possibleAnswers);
   var correctAnswers = questionAnswerRepository.GetCorrectAnswers(questions);
   var playerScore = playerScores.CountPlayerScoreBySum(playerAnswers, correctAnswers);

   var winScoreString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("WinScore");
   int winScore = 0;
   int.TryParse(winScoreString, out winScore);
```

Also sometimes abstraction is not a good thing, especially if there is no scope of scalling program in future. Do you have any ERD for your this app ? Your quiz app doesn't seems relational when it could be a good candidate - here's an example ERD I picked up from internet,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for so great answer! It is really useful! Have a nice day!